# Django Passing Newly Created ID from Models.Manager to Views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to pass the newly created id for a new entry from Models.Manager to views, so I can save it as a variable.

views.py

```
def save_form(request):
    item_a = request.POST['item_a']
    item_b = request.POST['item_b']
    Items.objects.save(item_a, item_b) 
    print (saved.id)
    return redirect ((reverse('project:index')))
```

models.py

```
class ItemsManager(models.Manager):
    def save(self, item_a, item_b)
        item_a = item_a
        item_b = item_b
        saved= Items.objects.create(
        item_a = item_a,
        item_b = item_b)
        return (True, saved)

class Items(models.Model):
    item_a=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item_b=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects = ItemsManager()
```

What I'm trying to do is get the id of the saved entry and send it to the views.

I tried using `return saved`, `return saved.id` and `return save.id` on the Models Manager to pass it to the views. Right now I have it as `True, saved` because it's what I've gather is the correct way after reading a few posts. However when I come to the views I'm not getting the id I want. When I try `print (saved.id)` in views I get:

> NameError: name 'saved' is not defined

I also tried in views `if save = [0]: print(saved.id)` and I get:

> if saved = [0]
>                ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Right now I'm just trying to print, but once I know the value is making it to the views I'll save the id as a variable.

I also tried `if save = True`

How can I pass the newly created id from the models.Manager to the views?

Any help would be appreciated.

Update

Now I changed views.py to:

```
    def save_form(request):
    item_a = request.POST['item_a']
    item_b = request.POST['item_b']
    Items.objects.save(item_a, item_b) 
    if save == True:
        print("hello")
    else:
        print ("bad luck!)
    return redirect ((reverse('project:index')))
```

It's saving the entries in the database and returning "bad luck". So save is somehow not == True.

Comment: The code you provided works fine for me (except mistype in line `saved= Items.objects,create(`), but judging by error messages you got I suppose you could make some other mistypes as well. Regarding the first error (`NameError: name 'result' is not defined`): I cannot see where `result` is even used here.

Comment: Really? It works for you? I corrected the misspellings(that you for pointing those out) and the "result" I think was because of all the different combinations I tried. I edited my question. Now I still have the 'return(True,saved)' in the models and added if save == True: print (it's true!) and it's not printing.

Comment: Do you assign the result of `Items.objects.save(item_a, item_b)` to some variables? Where do you get your `save` variable used in the next `if`?

Comment: @NikitinRoman Thanks for that observation. I needed to clarify the variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to be more specific with my variables.

models.py

```
class ItemsManager(models.Manager):
def save(self, item_a, item_b)
    item_a = item_a
    item_b = item_b
    saved= Items.objects.create(
    item_a = item_a,
    item_b = item_b)
    return (saved.id)

class Items(models.Model):
    item_a=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item_b=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    objects = ItemsManager()
```

views.py

```
def save_form(request):
item_a = request.POST['item_a']
item_b = request.POST['item_b']
save = Items.objects.save(item_a, item_b) 
print (save)
return redirect ((reverse('project:index')))
```

I passed the id from models using `return saved.id` after creating the object with `saved=Items.objects.create(...)`. Then in the views accessed it using `print(save)` since the return was based on  `save=Items.objects.save...`. It gave me the id from the newly created entry.